# Is there an integrated Eclipse plugin to debug Jython?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, debugging, jython

[JyDT](http://www.redrobinsoftware.net/jydt/) is a good Jython Eclipse plugin.

However, it doesn't allow Jython debugging in the Debug perspective.

Jython provides a command-line debugger (Pdb) but it operates outside Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pydev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/) has worked well for me.